# threejs How to rotate transformcontrol itself

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to rotate transformcontrol itself when object which attach to transformcontrol is rotate.

Before rotate

[image]

After rotate

[image]

As image shown, before rotate, cylinder's top direction is z-axis of transformcontrol, however after rotate is not.

I'd like that the transformcontrol's z axis to be always in the upward direction of the cylinder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TransformControls`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=transfo#examples/en/controls/TransformControls) returns an object that you can modify directly.

```js
const controls = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.setSpace('local');
controls.rotation.x = Math.PI / -2;
```

If you want to sync its rotation with your mesh, you can add it as a child of that mesh or use [`Euler#copy`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=euler#api/en/math/Euler).

```js
mesh.add(controls);

// or manually in a render loop, for example

scene.add(controls);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  controls.rotation.copy(mesh.rotation);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for comment.
I tried it you mentioned and transformcontrol rotated itself well.
However when I tried to control z-axis translate, attached object moved to global z-axis, not cylinder top direction.

Comment: I see. We can have it work from local coordinate space with [`TransformControls#setSpace`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=transform#examples/en/controls/TransformControls.setSpace), switching to `local` (defaults to `world`).